# Getting "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character" When aparently the response is correct

Tags: ajax, json

I'm crazy with this error, I'm traying to make an Ajax login form, this is my code:

My HTML:

```
         <div id='login-box' name='login-box' class='radius-all-tiny'>
            <div class='bt-wrapper bt-wrapper-hover'>
                <span class='bt-icon bt-icon-hover btn-users'></span>
            </div>
            <div id='login-banner' name='login-banner'>
                " . $content['SESSION_BANNER'] . "
            </div>
            <div class='radius-all-tiny' id='login-error' name='login-error'>
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            <form id='login-frm' name='login-frm' method='post' action='./'>
                <input type='text' id='usuario' name='usuario' placeholder='" . $content['SESSION_USER'] . "' />
                <input type='password' id='contrasena' name='contrasena' placeholder='" . $content['SESSION_PASS'] . "' />
                <div class='submit-wrap'><input class='bt-submit radius-all-medium' type='submit' id='enviar' name='enviar' value='" . $content['CONTACT_FRM_SEND'] . "' /></div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

My JS:

```
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // FORCE BROWSER NOT CACHE AJAX CALLS
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

            // HIDE ERROR DIALOG
            $('#login-error').hide();

            // LOGIN/OUT BUTTON BEHAVIOR
            $('#bt-login').click(function(){
                $('#login-error').hide();
                $.fancybox.open({
                    href : '#login-box',
                    padding : 0,
                    onClosed : function() { }
                });
            });

            // LOADING ANIMATION
            var ajaxload = '<img src=\"../img/components/spinner-dark.gif\" alt=\"" . $content['MAIN_LOADING'] . "\" />';

            $('#login-frm').bind('submit', function(){
                // AUTHENTICATING...
                // VALIDAMOS QUE NO HAYAN CAMPOS VACÍOS
                if (($('#usuario').val().length < 1) || ($('#contrasena').val().length < 1))
                {
                    $('#login-error').html('EMPTY');
                    $('#login-error').show();
                    return false;
                }

                // SI NO ESTÁN VACÍOS LOS CAMPOS, ENTONCES VALIDAMOS...
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    url: '../libs/class.log.in.out.php',
                    data: {usuario: $('#usuario').val(), contrasena: $('#contrasena').val()},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data)
                        {
                            if (data.success)
                            {
                                // ESCRIBIMOS LA VARIABLE DE SESIÓN
                                // CERRAMOS FANCYBOX
                                $.fancybox.close();
                                // RECARGAMOS LA PÁGINA PRINCIPAL
                                document.location.href = $('#urlactual');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // MOSTRAMOS ERROR DE AUTENTICACIÓN
                                $('#login-error').html('FAILED_AUTH');
                                $('#login-error').show();
                            }
                        }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
```

My class.log.in.out.php:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TRANSPORTADOR DE DATOS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
$data = array(
    'success' => false,
    'msg' => 'No se encontró ningún dato...'
);

// SOLICITAMOS LOS VALORES DE CONEXIÓN
$usr     = (isset($_REQUEST['usuario']) ? $_REQUEST['usuario'] : 'NULL');
$pwd     = (isset($_REQUEST['contrasena']) ? $_REQUEST['contrasena'] : 'NULL');

// VALIDAMOS LOS DATOS
class_exists('Database') || require ('class.database.php');
$resp = "";
$thisstt = false;
// INSTANCIAMOS LA CLASE DE BASE DE DATOS
$dbs = new Database();
$datos = $dbs->logIn($usr, $pwd, "", $thisstt);

if ($thisstt)
    $resp = $datos['usuario'];
else
    $resp = "" . $datos['error'] . " Usuario: " . $usr . "";

// DEVOLVEMOS EL ESTADO DE LA VALIDACIÓN
$data = array(
    'success' => $thisstt,
    'msg' => utf8_encode($resp)
);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// EMPAQUETADO DE DATOS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
echo json_encode($data);
```

I receive this response from de class.log.in.out.php (Using Firefox's developer tools):

When the authentication fail:

> {"success":false,"msg":"Los datos ingresados son incorrectos... Usuario: 123"}

When the authentication is correct:

> {"success":true,"msg":"gchinchilla"}

But Firefox says that the Syntax is incorrect, could you help me?

I apologize for my bad english, I'm learning it...

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using jQuery 1.11.0, I also tried the 1.10.2 version, but get the same error...

Comment: SOLVED! There was an "codification error", I have converted the PHP file from UTF-8 to UTF-8 Without BOM.

Answer (score 0):

i do not see any need of converting array to object for json_encode.

i will suggest using :

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

instead of :

```
echo json_encode((object)$data);
```

Comment: Thanks @sumit for your response, I'm getting the same "Syntax Error" after the change to "echo json_encode($data);"

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! There was an "codification error", I have converted the PHP file from UTF-8 to UTF-8 Without BOM.

More info here: http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark_.28BOM.29